# Best PDF app reader for iPad that emulates the paper book experience

Tags: pdf, ios

Good day.

I've used before PDF Expert by Readdle. But I really dislike seeing the gray spaces where the PDF ends and doesn't fit the entire screen. Now, I know that this is not "possible" per se, since PDF files are not meant to adapt to screen size, but I was wondering, is there any app for iPad with an option to "blur" that PDF ending and makes it seem like it fits the entire screen (even if it doesn't rearrange the content)?

I've looked everywhere on the AppStore, but haven't found anything similar to what I'm looking for. Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I'm aware that PDF Expert has a CROP option, that removes the PDF empty spaces to better fit the content on the screen, but in my experience it looks terrible because it zooms on the content.

Comment: Did you try the Adobe Reader? Works fine on my iPad.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [ibouquiniste](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibouquiniste/id527050465#?platform=ipad) it seems to fit to the edges by default has a nice flip page animation [image]

iBouquiniste Features Include:

- Supports notes
- Send books by email
- Unique Author Library (each author on their own bookshelf)
- View most recently opened books in the order you opened them
- Real page numbers
- Adjustable fonts, spacing, **margins**, book paper and more
- Download books via iTunes or any app supporting file transfer (i.e. Mail or Safari)
- OPDS catalogs support
- iBouquiniste Cloud Storage for synchronisation (books, reading positions, citations and bookmarks)

Comment: I’ve been struggling to find a help section for this app on how to import PDFs present on my iPhone to the library. Any suggestions?